# How to click a browser button with JavaScript automatically?

Tags: javascript, button, event-handling

How to click a button every second using JavaScript?

Comment: but... why? maybe some context would help? ie there could be a better way to achieve what you are trying to do... rather than 'click'ing a button every second...

Comment: Because http://www.decisionproblem.com/paperclips/

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
setInterval(function () {document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();}, 1000);
```

Comment: is that actually emulating a button click or just calling the event listener for `myButtonId`??

Comment: Can you do this by targeting a button by its class name instead?

Comment: @Kelseydh   Yes you could, but remember getElementsByClassName() will return an array of elements and not just one.  Therefore you would need to iterate over the array force the click execution. also note this method is present in I all current browsers but not available in some older browsers.   here is some reference. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: @Kelseydh.   I also answered this for a pure JAVASCRIPT impementation.   JQuery provides a slicker interface to handle this.

Answer (score 7):

This will give you some control over the clicking, and looks tidy

```
<script>
var timeOut = 0;
function onClick(but)
{
    //code
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    timeOut = setTimeout(function (){onClick(but)},1000);
}
</script>
<button onclick="onClick(this)">Start clicking</button>
```

Comment: Is there any reason this one clears and recreates its own timer every time it's called, as opposed to using `interval = setInterval(...)` which repeats on its own, and using `clearInterval(interval)` when necessary?

Comment: Each time you click it, it starts another loop, just figured I would halt it inside the loop so you could do a condition check before starting it again. Also, this is using `setTimeout` which is just to show an alternate method to `setInterval`

Comment: Alright, sure, this is a decent alternative depending on the effect someone wants. +1

Answer (score 5):

```
document.getElementById('youridhere').click()
```

Comment: This only partially answers the question, the repeating part of the question is still oustanding.

Answer (score 2):

This would work

```
setInterval(function(){$("#myButtonId").click();}, 1000);
```

Comment: Adding some description would help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    document.getElementById("yourbutton").click();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work ,simple and easy

```html
<form method="POST">
  <input  type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="save" value="send" name="send" id="send" style="width:20%;">
</form>
<script language ="javascript" >
  function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function() {
      document.getElementById("send").click();
    }, 10000);    
  }
</script>
```