# Auto Click a Button on a Web Site every 2 minutes?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

The title pretty much says it all. I am trying to get a specific button on a website clicked every 2 minutes so that I don't have to constantly press it myself. If I could automate this task that would make my job so much easier. Any suggestions as to what I can do? I have tried other solutions that simply refresh the entire page but that is quite inefficient. I've learned about tampermonkey (I use Chrome) but frankly I'm not sure as to how to proceed with writing a script for it.

Button Info:

```
<input type="button" id="00B30000008oQyK_refresh" src="s.gif" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:ListViewport.instances['00B30000008oQyK'].refreshList()" class="btn refreshListButton" title="Refresh">
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you need is a [client-side timer](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) that [clicks the button](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp) for you & also you need to [learn2search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515944/click-a-button-every-second).

Answer (score 1):

you can use an interval of 2 mins [Window setInterval() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdmafjpa/)

```
var button=document.getElementById("00B30000008oQyK_refresh");
setInterval(function(){ 
    button.click();
 }, 120000);
```

Comment: Can u please create a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pdmafjpa/